# C++ - Use enum from template class without template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T> class SomeClass{

public:
    enum SomeEnum{ SOME_FLAG};

};

SomeClass::SomeEnum some_enum =      SomeClass::SomeEnum::SOME_FLAG;       //NO
SomeClass<int>::SomeEnum some_enum = SomeClass::SomeEnum::SOME_FLAG;       //NO
SomeClass<int>::SomeEnum some_enum = SomeClass<int>::SomeEnum::SOME_FLAG;  //YES
```

This won't compile because

> class SomeClass used without template parameters

Is there no way / workaround to use it without template parameter, kinda make that enum *global* for that class, so it doesn't depend on the parameter.

It's not that I can't type them but they can be long and complicated, the code will be harder to read and I can't use something like auto here.
(I'm new to templates so sorry if this question is lame.)

Comment: Why can't you just define the enum outside the class (template)? At namespace scope. (I hope your project has a namespace...)

Comment: @Brian Simply defining them outside of the class means that they can conflict with other enum names within the project. (except when I define it as "enum SomeClass_SomeEnum{...}" but I wanted something more elegant than that.)

Comment: @AdyAdy You can use scoped enums if your problem is that names conflict.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to enclose your enum in a class definition for *reasons* (I cannot say what's the real problem), you can still introduce one more class that isn't a class template and contains the enum, then inherit from that with your class template. That's all.
As an example:

```
struct SomeBase {
    enum SomeEnum { SOME_FLAG };
};

template<typename>
struct SomeClass: SomeBase {
    // ...
};
```

Use this:

```
SomeBase::SomeEnum::SOME_FLAG;
```

Instead of this:

```
SomeClass::SomeEnum::SOME_FLAG;
```

Whenever you want to access the enum directly.
Something like the following remains valid anyway:

```
SomeClass<void>::SomeEnum foo = SomeClass<void>::SomeEnum::SOME_FLAG;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using MySomeClass = SomeClass<int>;

MySomeClass::SomeEnum foo = MySomeClass::SomeEnum::SOME_FLAG;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers